# Time not in 24 hour view

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

I am attempting to sum up hours per day across numerous fields. The issue I am encountering is when the sum passes 24 hour it defaults to 24 hour clock so 01:00:00 for 25 hours when actually I want it to show 25:00:00. Can anyone advise on this please? Many thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Depends how your data is formatted - what happens if you change the custom number format to this:
    [h]:mm:ss

[image]

Comment: I knew there had to be an easier way. :)

Answer (score 0):

The time is stored as a number by Excel and it will only show from 0 to 24 hours. If you format the cell as a number it should be 1.04 which Excel sees as 1.04 days and only uses the .04 when formatted as a time. Add *24 to your calculation and you will get 25.00.

It's a little more tricky to get your desired format hh:mm:as but I'll have a go and get back to you shortly.